# upload photos to fan page with android

Tags: facebook-android-sdk, fan-page

i want to upload photos to a fan Page's Wall (without being a Page Admin),

now i can make a post to the fan page wall, but i use the same method to do upload photos, it does works.

this is the upload photo part in the hackbook example,

```
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        /*
                                         * Source tag: upload_photo_tag
                                         */
                                        Bundle params = new Bundle();
                                        params.putString("url",
                                                "http://www.facebook.com/images/devsite/iphone_connect_btn.jpg");
                                        params.putString("caption",
                                                "FbAPIs Sample App photo upload");
                                      //id  148778808589468
                                        String access_token = Utility.mFacebook.getAccessToken();

                                        Utility.mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", params,
                                                "POST", new PhotoUploadListener(), null);
                                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't upload a photo object to a fan page if you are not a admin of that page. Of course you can post link of photo or video as a user but not the photo object itself. Although Facebook document says that a user can post photo object to a fan page, but it does not do so. Every one facing the same problem. If you try to post photo object as per the document the photo will be get posted to your wall instead of fan page wall.